# How to use custom icon for polyline?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Simple question that I couldn't find an answer to.

So lets say my image(icon) is in a local path: 'images/icon1.png'
How do I use it as an icon to display along the path of a polyline ?

This is one example of my polyline:

```
icon_setting = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale:1.4,

}; 

green_polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path_array,
    icons: [{
        icon: icon_setting,
        offset: '0',
        repeat: '100px'
    }],
    strokeColor: '#00FF00',
    strokeOpacity: 0.3,
    strokeWeight: 4,
});
```

I tried to find a way to give "path:" the local icon path but couldn't do it. There is a way to use custom icons for markers but I couldn't adapt this way to use with polyline.

Also worth mentioning I'm quite new to js and the maps-api so bare that in mind.

Thanks for your help, every answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an image to a polyline, it has to be an SVG symbol.

You can write your own code to put your image icon along the polyline (as marker icons would be one option), but the syntax in your question only works with [Symbols](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols)

Comment: Thanks I did stumble upon this method of using "custom icons" along the path of a polyline but the syntax and method was very complex and I thought there should be another, more simple, way to use really (not drawn with syntax) custom icons.

Comment: Can you make your .png (or something enough like it) with SVG (Symbols only really support one path though)?

Comment: I guess it's the only way to go so I need to figure out how to make my icon or something similar with SVG, got any suggestions where to start looking ?